# Buttons with non-standard shapes

Tags: android, imagebutton

I need to create my `layout.xml` with non-standard shaped Buttons.
For instance, here is an image of what I want to do: there are three triangle buttons and my question is: how can I currently build my `layout.xml` so that these buttons do not overlap each other?

[image]

---

**PS:** don't post code, I just want to know how to do this. But if it's not difficult for U... )))

Answer (score 0):

You should use onTouchListener instead of onClickListener and get the touched co-ordinate’s by using MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, then check whether coordinates belonged to image.

Refer [this link](http://www.starkdigital.net/irregular-shape-clickable-android) for more help